# php condition for all pages except one specific page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a php condition to target all wordpress pages except one specific page. I need to target ONLY pages (not posts or post types or taxonomies).
So my condition needs to say "if it is a page which is not called mypage then do this"

I have the following, however it doesn't work. As you can see below, the two conditions overflow with eachother....

```
if(is_page('mypage') ||  && ! is_page()) { 
// mystuff here
}
```

EDIT:
Here is more info as I may not have explained things correctly.
What I am trying to do is to dequeue the block style css that are being loaded. I need to do it EVERYWHERE except on pages (but only if that page is not called mypage).

(So it must be dequeued everywhere (post taxonomies etc.) except on pages, but not if that page is called mypage)

```
if(is_page('mypage') && is_page()) {
wp_dequeue_style('wp-block-library');
wp_dequeue_style('wp-block-library-theme');
wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-vendors-style');
wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-style');
}
```

Comment: Maybe `if(is_page() && !is_page('mypage'))`

Comment: is_page('mpage') means "if the page is called 'mypage' ". So revise slightly by adding the ! (not operator) should do what you want.

Comment: @KenLee But then it could also be a post

Comment: Right, so please use your code is_page to specify it is not a post, I just want to explain a bit to OP

Comment: Thanx for your help, however, I added more info to my question. Sorry I think I didn't properly explain things.

Comment: So `if(is_page('mypage') || !is_page()) {` should work - If you're on `mypage` this will return `true`, if you're on something other than page then it will also return  `true` and if you're on any page (other than `mypage`) it will return `false`